# How To Convert a Single Byte to a String

Tags: c#

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2010.

I want to convert a byte (8 bit int) to a string that's one character long. I need to do this because I want to send the byte value over serial to an Arduino.

For example, let's say

```
byte myByte = 49;
```

49 is the ASCII code for the character "1". I want to convert myByte into myString, such that if I did

```
serialport1.Write(myString);
```

It would function the same as

```
serialport1.Write("1");
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried just writing the byte to the serial port using the Write byte overload.

Comment: That's actually what I wound up doing. I just assumed Write only did strings.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[]{myByte})
```

Comment: Use '(char)mybyte'  or '((char)mybyte).ToString()'. Always make it simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
serialport1.Write(Convert.ToChar(myByte).ToString());
```

See also: [Convert.ToChar Method (Byte)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hcy5390%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: ..." to its equivalent ***Unicode*** character". This only almost ASCII.

Comment: ASCII is a subset of Unicode, and why not support Unicode?

Comment: Mainly because that's not what the OP asked for :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure want to use ASCII?

If so, you should protect yourself from unconvertible data. One way is to have an exception thrown when the data is not ASCII:

```
var bytes = new Byte[]{myByte};
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("US-ASCII", new EncoderExceptionFallback(), 
          new DecoderExceptionFallback());
var myString = encoding.GetString(bytes);
```

`System.Text.Encoding.ASCII` would replace unconvertible data with `?`, which silently covers up problems and creates strange symptoms.

Comment: You are correct! I had assumed that, in order to send a byte over serial, I would have to convert to ASCII first. However, this didn't work because ASCII only goes to 127, not 255. I looked at the .write overloads, and found that by making myByte an array that's one long `byte[] myByte = {184};` I could send it by doing `serialPort1.write(myByte, 0 ,1);`

I upvoted you, but the best answer to the question asked was the first one. Thanks a million though!

Comment: Consider this: Many people used to surf the WWW and download binaries over serial! You might also want to look at [SerialPort.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone else: I had to do something similar in a loop and had issues getting the resultant string to print. The answer was to use spender's solution from above, but wrapped to check for null bytes before adding to my string:

```
string result = "";
foreach (byte myByte in myArray)
{
    if (myByte != (byte)00000000)
    {
        result += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[]{myByte})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is casting the byte to a char, then converting it to a string:

```
    public string SingleByteToString(byte ಠ_ಠ)
    {
        return ((char)(ಠ_ಠ)).ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
byte byteVal = 49;
serialport1.Write(System.Convert.ToString(byteValue));
```

Comment: That seems to return the literal string. For example,
`System.Convert.ToString(49)`
returns "49", not "1".